# Show UIPickerView when editing UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

I want to show a UIPickerView and not the keyboard when I edit a UITextField. I tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    depCityField.inputView=pickerDestinations;
    comeCityField.inputView=pickerDestinations;
}
```

It doesn't work, but with UIDatePicker it works fine...

Comment: Can I know the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Deepak When i click on the textField there are nothing

Comment: @Deepak @Siddharth maybe i should put inormation in the picker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created an example programmatically for your reference. I really hope this helps you. This is the [`source`](http://pastie.org/1962865).

Comment: thak you very very much !! i tried to adabt it to my code but still don't work :( now when i click the textfield the picker appear but there are nothing . I should use init mehod to set values ? i can add values after create it ? this is my code http://pastie.org/private/qf9ugcgmiqui0nox9qiw and thank you again

Comment: It work :) i maked this - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"New York", @"Chicago", @"Memphis", @"California", @"Seattle",@"London",@"Paris", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationsPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init]; .

But how to call the method  - (void)onLocationSelection; ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your textFields dont have the delegate set. You need to set the UIViewController as the delegate to the textFields.

Your viewDidLoad should probably look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad()
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    depCityField.delegate = self;
    comeCityField.delegate = self;

    depCityField.inputView=pickerDestinations;
    comeCityField.inputView=pickerDestinations;
}
```

Comment: dharth it don't work and i have a warning " Assinign to ... incompatible type..."